# What shared, high volume storage technology should be used when hosting in Google Cloud?

Tags: nfs, google-cloud-platform, nfs4, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

Given an auto-scaling web server farm setup that needs access to a very large number of image files, we are currently using Google Cloud Storage with a mounted FUSE folder on each web server so that the same set of shared files can be accessed.

The performance when accessing / reading GCS publicly shared files is excellent, however any write operations using gsutil or through FUSE ( which of course uses the same API ) seem painfully slow, relatively speaking.  As is mentioned here:  [Google Cloud Storage Fuse vs GlusterFS, pros, cons and costs](https://serverfault.com/questions/752637/google-cloud-storage-fuse-vs-glusterfs-pros-cons-and-costs)

Tempted to setup an NFS container VM with a large disk, however eventually the shared image folder is expected to reach into terabyte size ranges.

What is the best way to host a very large number of image files on Google Cloud while maintaining fast write performance?  Preferably one that scales well.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Compute Engine, you can use a [single NFS](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#single-node-file-server), the instance type that you choose will determine the [egress caps on write throughput](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#egress_performance_cap).

If you're looking for scalability, you might consider using [GlusterFS](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#glusterfs) that scales to hundreds of terabytes or [Avere vFXT](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#avere-vfxt) for petabytes of storage and millions of IOPS.